# Exception parse error parity

Tags: python

Estoy intentando evaluar la derivada de una funcion con el evaluador de funciones parser, el problema es que cuando sympy me devuelve los exponentes representados asi "**" y mi evaluador no entiende que eso es potencia, el esta esperando un simbolo ^ entonces me arroja ese error de parity.
primero hago los imports que voy a necesitar. Despues sympy requiere que defina variables, es lo que hago con decir x = Symbol('x') defino mi funcion f y saco su derivada con el metodo de SymPy diff. convierto ese resultado en un string porque el evaluador recibe strings, luego evaluo ese resultado en el evaluador y funciona con la funcion que esta alli, f = x^2 derivada = 2*x evaluada en 2 = 4. PERO si yo intento evaluar digamos f = x^3 derivada = 3*x^2 (este ^ lo devuelve como dos asteriscos *) evaluada en 2 genera el error Exception: parse error [column 6]: parity
entonces aqui lo que necesito es alguna forma de que mi evaluador sepa que ** es elevar o que el resultado de derivar que me devuelve el metodo diff me deuelva las potencias asi ^, estoy pensando en alguna solucion pero hasta ahora no consigo nada porfavor ayudaaaa.

```
from sympy import *
#from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from py_expression_eval import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = Parser()
p.ops2['^'] = np.power
p.ops1['sin'] = np.sin
p.ops1['tan'] = np.tan
p.ops1['cos'] = np.cos
p.ops1['log'] = np.log
p.consts['e'] = np.e

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
f = 'x^2'
derivada = diff(f, x)
derivadaStr = str(derivada)
print(derivada)

print(p.parse(derivadaStr).evaluate({'x': 2}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi propia solucion pero espero mejores soluciones y.y

```
from sympy import *
#from numpy import *
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import *
from py_expression_eval import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p = Parser()
p.ops2['^'] = np.power
p.ops1['sin'] = np.sin
p.ops1['tan'] = np.tan
p.ops1['cos'] = np.cos
p.ops1['log'] = np.log
p.consts['e'] = np.e

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')
f = 'x^3'
derivada = diff(f, x)
derivadaStr = str(derivada)
derivadaStr2 = derivadaStr.replace("**", "^")
print(derivadaStr2)

print(p.parse(derivadaStr2).evaluate({'x': 2}))
```